# PHP page is blank from trying to run a register script with my DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am working on a project and I have a registration form for users to fill out. The form then also populates the database with other variables.

For the life of me though, I cant figure out why the screen is loading a blank white page.. I have been following some tutorials from youtube and trying to apply them to my existing pages but so far no dice.

Here's the PHP code Im working with. The tutorial I followed worked flawlessly when used on a blank page, but once I edited it for my own use, it no longer wants to run:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
$username = protect($_POST['username']);
$password = protect($_POST['password']);
$email = protect($_POST['email']);
$email2 = protect($_POST['email2']);
$password2 = protect($_POST['password2']);
$commname = protect($_POST['commname']);
$outpostname = protect($_POST['outpost']);
$special = protect($_POST['specialty']);

if($username == "" || $password == "" || $email == "" || $password2 == "" || $email2 == "" || $commname == "" || $outpostname == "" || $special == "no"){
    echo "Please supply all required fields!";
}elseif(strlen($username) > 20){
    echo "Username must be less than 20 characters!";
}elseif(strlen($email) > 100){
    echo "E-mail must be less than 100 characters!";
    }elseif(strlen($email2) > 100){
    echo "E-mail verify must be less than 100 characters!";
}else{
    $register1 = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `username`='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    $register2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email`='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($register1) > 0){
        echo "That username is already in use!";
    }elseif(mysql_num_rows($register2) > 0){
        echo "That e-mail address is already in use!";
    }else{
        $spec = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['specialty']);
        $comnam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['commname'[);
        $postnam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['outpost'[);                                                    
        $ins1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stats` (`credits`,`food`,`land`,`energy`,`turns`,`turns_max`,`gas`,`ore`,`population`,`buildeff`,`offpts`,`defpts`,`score`) VALUES (2000,2000,100,2000,30,30,2000,2000,500,100,0,0,0)") or die(mysql_error());
        $ins2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `unit` (`trainee`,`juggernaut`,`infantry`,`marauder`,`terminator`,`reconsq`,`prisoner`,`destroyer`,`colossus`) VALUES (100,0,50,0,0,0,0,0,0)") or die(mysql_error());
        $ins3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`colonynum`,`username`,`password`,`email`,`specialty`,`commname`,`outpostname`) VALUES (0,'$username','".md5($password)."','$email','$spec','$comnam','$postnam')") or die(mysql_error());
        $ins4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `structure` (`agridome`,`spaceport`,`barrack`,`researchfac`,`laserbat`,`factory`,`infirmary`,`trainingfac`) VALUES (1,0,5,0,0,0,1,1,)") or die(mysql_error());
        header('Location: aurora/main.php');
    }
}
} ?>
```

I know its pretty "ugly" but I am trying to learn :)

if you need the form Im using let me know.. shouldnt matter though. I have all the ID's set right with correct spelling etc.

Comment: $comnam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['commname'[);
$postnam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['outpost'[);  both have inverted closing brackets. What are you using to develop, any good code editor should show you these errors

Comment: using dreamweaver.. so it catches virtually nothing. I need to switch over to my windows machine and use phpdesigner which I have, I just never use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have invalid syntax in your code, that is why showing blank screen. Replace this, Use `$_POST['commname']` instead of `$_POST['commname'[`

```
$comnam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['commname']);
 $postnam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['outpost']);
```

instead of

```
$comnam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['commname'[);
 $postnam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['outpost'[);
```

Note: Use mysqli_* or PDO instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: ah, there we go. the rest of my script doesnt quite work but I at least got past that.
Fatal error: Call to undefined function protect() in register.php on line 78

Comment: `protect()` function not included, that is the reason.

Comment: I added the protect function now. Now it loads fine, but doesnt post anything to the DB. it just refreshes the page. perhaps missing a connect(); somewhere